# Transformacion de int a long en Arduino

Tags: arduino

Estoy comenzando con arduino , y me esta dando problemas a la hora de realizar operaciones , he indagado un poco y resulta que si te sobrepasas de **int** deberias pasar a **long** añadiendo una L a tu entero como bien dice la [documentacion de arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/constants/integerconstants/) (en ingles).

Pero no se / no consigo hacerlo sin cambiar todo a **long** lo que sinceramente me parece una guarrada ¿Ideas?

```
float calculatePercentage(int value_humidity){
 int max_level = 790
 long multiplication = max_level *100L;
 return multiplication/max_level;
}
```

Comment: Ese ejemplo que pones no tiene pies ni cabeza. Y la conversión a `long` se produce aunque no pongas la `L`. ¿ Exactamente, que quieres hacer ?

Comment: Basicamente , yo tengo un numero que entra perfectamente en un int (790 en el ejemplo) que al multiplicarlo(*100 en el ejemplo) excedo el valor del int por defecto (32767) y quiero que la variable resultante sea un long . Ahora mismo no lo hace , se fija el valor al maximo del int (32767),

Comment: Basta con que uno de los operando sea un `long`. O usas una variable, o usas un literal. ¿ Que problema hay con usar `L` ? Veo que ya conoces la promoción de tipos, y que lo estás haciendo bien. No se exactamente que es lo que quieres conseguir.